# Show that if $m^2/n^2 < 2 $, $\frac{(m+2n)^2}{(m+n)^2}-2<2-\frac{m^2}{n^2}$

Tags: inequality

Given $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, I want to show that $m^2/n^2 < 2$ implies first that

$$\frac{(m+2n)^2}{(m+n)^2} > 2\quad (1)$$

and using this, that

$$\frac{(m+2n)^2}{(m+n)^2} -2 < 2 - \frac{m^2}{n^2}$$

I've done the first by working backwards and seeing what the steps were which are required, but the second I can't seem to figure out. In particular, I've tried fiddling around with adding and subtracting $(1)$ with $0 < 2- m^2/n^2$, but I can't get the inequality or parity the right way. Would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Try this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069310/need-help-with-proof-for-dedekind-cuts-on-mathbbq/2076052#2076052

Answer (score 1):

First consider
$$\frac{(m+2n)^2}{(m+n)^2}-2=\frac{-m^2+2n^2}{(m+n)^2}.$$

NEW CONTENT ADDED IN EDIT

For convenience put $a=m/n$, so we assume that $a>0$ and $a^2<2$.
Then
$$n=\frac{m+2n}{m+n}=\frac{a+2}{a+1}.$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
4-a^2-b^2&=4-a^2-\frac{a^2+4a+4}{a^2+2a+1}\\
&=\frac{-a^4-2a^3+2a^2+4a}{(a+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{a(a+2)(2-a^2)}{(a+1)^2}>0.
\end{align}$$

Comment: So I've got that the question is equivalent to showing $\frac{2n^2-m^2}{(m+n)^2}<\frac{(n-m)(n+m)}{n^2}$, and I've tried completing squares, working backwards etc... but I'm still not sure how to get to it

Answer (score 0):

If
$m/n = r$,
then
$s
=\frac{m+2n}{m+n} 
=\frac{m/n+2}{m/n+1} 
=\frac{r+2}{r+1} 
$.

If $r \ge 1$
then
$s 
= 1+\dfrac1{r+1}
\gt 1$
and
$s \le \dfrac32
$.

$s^2-2
=\frac{(r+2)^2}{(r+1)^2}-2
=\frac{r^2+4r+4-2(r^2+2r+1)}{r^2+2r+1}
=\frac{-r^2+2}{r^2+2r+1}
$.

Therefore
if $r^2 < 2$
then
$s^2 > 2$
and
if $r^2 > 2$
then
$s^2 < 2$.

Also,
if $r \ge 1$,
$\dfrac{|s^2-2|}{|r^2-2|}
=\dfrac1{(r+1)^2}
\le \dfrac14
$
so that
$s^2-2$ is closer to $2$
than
$r^2-2$.