# Find a rational number that is greater than $t$ where $t^2<2$

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

I have trouble in proving this, that is if $t\in Q\land t^2<2$, then there exists another rational number $q$ such that $q>t\land q^2<2$. May I ask how to find this rational number?

Comment: Are you allowed to use $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: No, because $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: There are a number of posts on this site that give an explicit example.

Comment: $q=t+\frac1 n$ with $n >\frac 5 {2-t^{2}}$ will do.

Comment: Try $q=\frac{4t}{t^2+2}$ (assuming $t>0$, otherwise use $q=1$), constructed using some AM-GM intuitions. A different intuition (say, Newton's method) will also make a possibly different $q$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you mean expanding the term? The term is complicating though.

Comment: After expanding the square you can use the following facts: $t <2$ (becasue $t^{2}<2<4$) and $\frac 1 {n^{2}} <\frac1  n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry for being a downer. Was a bit frustrated after many failed attempts. May I ask how did you come up with this trick? The reason for me to study real analysis is because I am bad at algebraic tricks. Any texts recommended for improvements?

Comment: @AndesLam: there is not much of a trick. Just take a number $t+h$ where $h$ is positive and try to analyze the equation $(t+h) ^2<2$ ie $0<h(2t+h)<2-t^2$. The thing to note is that you are not supposed to solve this inequality but rather find any $h$ which satisfies this. Attempts to solve inequalities is to miss the point of analysis.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Interesting critique of my answer, which I have just deleted.  I must admit that you have a point.  Although the idea that the decimal expansion of $\sqrt{2}$ is infinite is fairly elementary, the OP did comment that he is not allowed to *use* $\sqrt{2}$.  I simply didn't notice that comment.  Also, the OP did emphasize the premise that $t \in \mathbb{Q}$, which **is** irrelevant to my approach.

Comment: Another approach which shows the existence of $q$ without finding it explicitly is given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/514496/72031). The argument in that answer is typical of many arguments used in analysis proofs.

Comment: @user2661923: although you have deleted your answer, I hope you have taken my comment in positive spirit. You will observe that the problem becomes more interesting if one remains within $\mathbb {Q} $. Also the point of the problem (my guess) is to highlight issues with $\mathbb{Q} $ and the need to extend it to $\mathbb {R} $.

Comment: @WillJagy: yes Pell equation and the related continued fractions help a lot here to find nice approximations.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069310/need-help-with-proof-for-dedekind-cuts-on-mathbbq/2076052#2076052) for an exact procedure how to construct such a $q$ from $t$.

Comment: @rtybase  note 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&2 \\
1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)^2 =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3&4 \\
2& 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
as in my answer below

Comment: @rtybase: So this question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2069310/42969, isn't it?

Comment: @MartinR the questions themselves sound different, although yes, probably a duplicate on a very careful reading.

Answer (score 1):

If $t$ is negative or zero, we can use $1$ as bigger.

If $t$ is already positive, we can write it as $ t = \frac{p}{q}$ with positive integers $p,q.$  The requirement that $  \left( \frac{p}{q} \right)^2 < 2$ tells us that
$$  p^2 - 2 q^2 < 0 $$
We choose
$$  w = \frac{3p+4q}{2p+3q}= \frac{3t+4}{2t+3}  .   $$
As
$$  \left( 3p+4q  \right)^2 - 2 \left( 2p+3q \right)^2 = p^2 - 2 q^2 < 0$$
we see that $w^2 < 2$
At the same time
$$  w - t  = \frac{3p+4q}{2p+3q}  - \frac{p}{q} = \frac{-2(p^2 - 2 q^2)}{q(2p+3q)}  > 0 $$

The reasons for doing this: every quadratic form, in this case $x^2 - 2 y^2,$  has an automorphism group; we use a matrix that generates the group, which is  a recipe once we find the first nontrivial Pell solution, $3^2 - 2 \cdot 2^2 = 1$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3&2 \\
4&3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&0 \\
0&-2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3&4 \\
2&3 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&0 \\
0& -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

note: many binary quadratic forms also have an automorphism of negative determinant, in this case we could negate one variable while leaving the other fixed. The entire group is defined once we add a single instance of that onto the infinite cyclic group  of automorphisms with positive determinant

Answer (score 0):

Let $q=t+h$ where WLOG $0<h<1$ and $q>0$. Then we want $q^2+2qh+h^2 <2$ but $h^2\leq h$ so it is enough to have $q^2 +2qh+h<2$  or $$h<\frac{2-q^2}{1+2q}$$