# Can the Stern-Brocot tree be employed for better convergence of $2^m/3^n$?

Tags: limits, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, trees

Prerequisite reading:

1. [Can any positive real be approximated as $2^m/3^n$ with $(m,n)$ large enough?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3981318/can-any-positive-real-be-approximated-as-2m-3n-with-m-n-large-enough)
2. [Stern Brocot tree sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606772/stern-brocot-tree-sequence)

Something unsatisfactory is going on with convergence of $\,2^m/3^n\,$ towards a positive real $\,r\,$. As soon as we have reached sufficient approximation,
the next step in our current iteration procedure is to increase $\,m \to m+1\,$ if $\,2^m/3^n < r\,$ or to increase $\,n \to n+1\,$ if $\,2^m/3^n > r\,$.
But then we have actually destroyed our approximation so far, according to $\,2^m/3^n \to 2.2^m/3^n\,$ or $\,2^m/3^n \to 2^m/3^n/3\,$ respectively.
Thus it looks like we are starting all over every time again without making much progress. The number of iterations needed indeed is very large.
Reason why I have been looking for a procedure that does not have this drawback, i.e. where the next approximation is always closer to the desired outcome.
This is what I have tried so far.

According to question (2.),
*for every positive real number $0 \lt g \lt 1$ , there exists an infinite sequence in the Stern Brocot tree [ .. ] that converges to the real number.*
Meanwhile, this question has [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606772/stern-brocot-tree-sequence/4000446#4000446),
and the main result in there reads as follows:
$$
- \frac{1}{n_1(n_1+n_2)} \lt g - \frac{m_1+m_2}{n_1+n_2} \lt \frac{1}{(n_1+n_2)n_2}
$$
In view of question (1.), we substitute $\ln(2)/\ln(3)$ for that number $g$. Then it follows that:
$$
- \frac{1}{n_1(n_1+n_2)} \lt \frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(3)} - \frac{m_1+m_2}{n_1+n_2} \lt \frac{1}{(n_1+n_2)n_2} \\
- \frac{\ln(3)}{n_1} \lt \ln(2)(n_1+n_2) - \ln(3)(m_1+m_2) \lt + \frac{\ln(3)}{n_2} \\
\ln\left(3^{-1/n_1}\right) \lt \ln\left(\frac{2^{n_1+n_2}}{3^{m_1+m_2}}\right) \lt \ln\left(3^{+1/n_2}\right) \\
3^{-1/n_1} \lt \frac{2^{n_1+n_2}}{3^{m_1+m_2}} \lt 3^{+1/n_2}
$$
The search through the Stern-Brocot tree can be pictured. The blue line is the function $\,\color{blue}{x\ln(2)-y\ln(3)=0}\,$, small circles are fractions,
mapped on a grid $\,m/n \to (m,n)\,$, massively black filled dots are the fractions in the Stern-Brocot tree. It is seen that searching through
the tree is much more efficient than increasing $m$ and $n$ with increments one at a time.

[image]

Now compare the expression at the second line of the above formulas with an analogous expression in reference (1.):
$$
\ln(2)(n_1+n_2) - \ln(3)(m_1+m_2) \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad m\ln(2) - n\ln(3) - \ln(r)
$$
And be prepared for a disappointment: the logarithm of the arbitrary real $r$ is missing! Or alternatively: $\ln(r)=0$ or $r=1$.
This means that our "infinite search" through the Stern-Brocot tree, though highly efficient, finally arrives at an approximation only for the number one.
I find this weird, because - graphically - there doesn't seem to be a great difference between $\color{red}{2^m/3^n \to r}$ and $\color{blue}{2^m/3^n \to 1}$:

[image]

Hence the QUESTION: does there exist a means for adapting the Stern-Brocot procedure such that it works for reals other than one?

EDIT.

Here comes another graph that shows the astonishing convergence with the Stern-Brocot method, in comparison with analogous pictures in my Q & A  
[Can any positive real be approximated as $2^m/3^n$ with $(m,n)$ large enough?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3981318/can-any-positive-real-be-approximated-as-2m-3n-with-m-n-large-enough/4006103#4006103) :

[image]

Comment: Are you just trying to show that any positive real can be approximated as such? Or are you trying to show a specific approach with the Stern-Brocot procedure?

Comment: @openproblem: The latter, actually. An extremely concise _existence proof_ has already been given in an
[answer by lhf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3981318/can-any-positive-real-be-approximated-as-2m-3n-with-m-n-large-enough/3981335#3981335)
But what I am looking for is a way of _constructing_ fractions $2^m/3^n$ that approach a given real $r$ more efficiently than in question (1).
I have proved that such a procedure exists for $r=1$, by employing the Stern-Brocot tree. But any other method is quite welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I will give an approach which doesn't use the Stern-Brocot procedure.

It suffices to show that $\frac{2^{m}}{3^{n}}$ is dense in the interval [1,2]. Since taking $\alpha\in (0,\infty)$ outside this interval there is some $k\in Z$ so that $\alpha = 2^{k}\gamma $ for some $\gamma \in [1,2]$. Then we know there is a sequence in $\frac{2^{m}}{3^{n}}$ which approaches $\gamma$, multiplying the sequence termwise by $2^{k}$ (possibly taking a tail of the sequence), we get a sequence in $\frac{2^{m}}{3^{n}}$ which approaches $\alpha$.

Next consider that the map $f:[1,2] -> [0,1]$ with $f(x) = log_{2}(x)$ is a bijection.

The image of $\frac{2^{m}}{3^{n}}$ under the map is $N-Nlog_{2}(3)$. So it is enough to show that $N-Nlog_{2}(3)$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

This is a consequence of Weyl's Equidistribution theorem, which is a special case of the Ergodic theorem.

Consider $a=2-log_{2}(3) = log_{2}(\frac{4}{3})$, so $a$ is in the image of the set, So is $na = log_{2}(\frac{4^{n}}{3^{n}})$ and so is the fractional part of $na$.

The weyl Equidistribution theorem (which is not a trivial result) shows that for irrational a the fractional part of $na$ is uniformly distributed and hence dense on [0,1]. Since $2-log_{2}(3)$ is irrational you can use this theorem.

Comment: Unfortunately, an existence proof does not answer the question. Please absorb the above comment of mine. I'm more of a programmer (constructivist) than a theoretician.

Comment: @HandeBruijn Sorry about that, I wrote the response hours before you got back to my question. I'll leave the post up since I don't think it is worthless. If the community think that the post is worthless I'll delete it eventually. I don't know enough about Stern Brocot trees to answer the original question. Hopefully someone else will come along who knows more about the topic. Best of luck.

Comment: Agreed. Your response is certainly of value. Any downvote will not be mine :-)

Comment: Some suggestions of yours have been absorbed into my own
[Heuristics of a another proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3981318/can-any-positive-real-be-approximated-as-2m-3n-with-m-n-large-enough/4006103#4006103).
Would you please take a look at it and eventually tell me how to complete the last part of it: why is $\,\ln(2^m/3^n/r)\,$ uniformly distributed?
Reason: I don't understand your proof quite well and the same holds for [the proof by lhf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3981318/can-any-positive-real-be-approximated-as-2m-3n-with-m-n-large-enough/3981335#3981335).